# kubernetes "remote error: tls: handshake failure" missing SSL certificates

Tags: ssl, kubernetes, ssl-certificate, k3s

I have a private docker image repository, that needs SSL certificates in order to be accessible.
Now I have tried creating multiple kubernetes secrets (containing docker host-name, username and pass and certificates) so I can fetch images with kubernetes from it, but it is still failing because of the missing certificates "Failed to pull image .... remote error: tls: handshake failure". So is there a specific way one need to apply SSL certificates in order to be able to pull images from private repository that requires SSL certificates.

I have tried

```
kubectl create secret docker-registry repo-auth --docker-server=xxxxx --docker-username=xxxxxx --docker-password=xxxx

kubectl create secret tls repo-tls --cert=/xxxx/client.cert --key=/xxxx/client.key"

kubectl create secret generic regcred2 --from-file=/xxxx/client.key --from-file=/xxxx/client.cert"

kubectl create secret generic regcred --from-file=.dockerconfigjson=/root/.docker/config.json --type=kubernetes.io/dockerconfigjson --from-file=/xxxx/client.key --from-file=/xxxx/client.cert"

imagePullSecrets:
    - name: repo-tls
    - name: repo-auth
    - name: regcred
    - name: regcred2
```

but the error still remains

PS I am using k3s

Answer (score 1):

You problem seems like an issue with fetching images from private-docker-registry.

You can perform the following steps to use an ssl certificate for authenticating your pull-request for fetching images form a docker registry:

1. You need to store your ssl certificate in a kubernetes secret. (Refer: https://www.padok.fr/en/blog/kubernetes-secrets)
   You can use following command to create a secret from ssl file:

   `kubectl create secret generic ssl-key-cert --from-file=ssl.key --from-file ssl.cert`
2. Update the pod yaml with imagePullSecret attribute and provide the 'secret-name' created in first step as the value to this attribute. (Refer:https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/pull-image-private-registry/)

Comment: can I somehow combine these two secrets "kubectl create secret generic ssl-key-cert --from-file=ssl.key --from-file ssl.cert" with "kubectl create secret docker-registry privaterepo --docker-server=xxxx --docker-username=xxx --docker-password=xxx" . Or do I just add multiple secrets under imagePullSecrets.

Comment: Yes. You can use

`kubectl create secret docker-registry privaterepo --docker-server=xxxx --docker-username=xxx --docker-password=xxx --from-file=ssl-key-path --from-file=ssl-cert-path `

Comment: I have tried different approaches of passing the certs, but still the error remains the same. Do you perhaps know if there is some official Kubernetes documentation for working with repositories that require certificates.

Comment: You may want to look at this resource: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/images/#configuring-nodes-to-authenticate-to-a-private-registry